# Can I imbue more than once on the same difficulty level in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

After getting the Horadric Malus and bringing it back to Charsi, she gives you the chance to imbue an item to make it better. I know you can do it again on the next difficulty, but I want to do it again on the SAME difficulty. Another cheap way is to save before doing it, and if you don't get good results you can end the task of the game so it doesn't save and do it again.

**But is there a way to do this more than once in the same game? And on multiple items?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple and short answer: ***NO***

You can only use `Imbue` once per difficulty level. As you mentioned you can save and kill the task, but you can't do it several times. Other option is to create new characters and do that quest on them.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's better to save your imbues for the later levels as then you will be able to get the full benefit of you imbues. Even though  you might be able to aim for certain affixes by imbuing at a specific level, the higher you are above a certain affix modifier level, the greater chance it will spawn. Level 80 as the recommended minimum level for any character, but some people might not be able to easily reach level 80 but still would like to imbue. I would say around 67 is the an absolute bare minimum level if you want to get good affixes.

Answer (score 3):

Imbue only works on white items so you cannot imbue a rare item.

If rerolling is what you want to do, there are [2 cube recipes](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Guide:Crafting_Cubing_and_Socketing_v1.10,_by_Uzziah) for doing so:

> Rare item rerolling recipes
>
> There are 2 recipes for rerolling rares. Both I consider expensive. One of which I have never been able to try do to not having the ingredients.
>
> - 1 pskull, 1 SOJ, 1 rare item = 1 rare item; ilvl = 0.6 ilvl + 0.6 clvl
> - 6 pskulls, 1 rare item = 1 rare item; ilvl = 0.4ilvl +0.4clvl

Comment: the question was about using `Imbue` function several times on a same difficulty, and not using `Imbue` on the same item several times

Comment: @Novarg That said, this is a useful answer, and does point to a good alternate for imbuing in the rare re-rolling recipes.